# What's the relationship between Reactive-Extension and ReactiveX

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5, reactivex, reactive-extensions-js

What's the difference/relationship between those two github groups:

- Reactive-Extensions (https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions)
- ReactiveX (https://github.com/ReactiveX)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding RxJS there're two main version right now.

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS - RxJS 4 is the older RxJS implementation.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS - RxJS 5 is the new RxJS implementation rewritten from scratch. It was in development since RxJS 2 (for a couple of years) so they made it into a separate repository instead. This RxJS 5 is supposed to replace the older RxJS 4.

However I can't tell why for example RxJava is in https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava and not https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJava while with with RxCpp is exactly the other way around.